# Como modificar los estilos de Modal Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, modal

La cuestión es que tengo en el html de mi proyecto angular el siguiente codigo de un modal arrastrable y redimensionable, el cual se muestra al hacer click en un boton:

```
<div>
    
    <button type="button" (click)="modalAcerca.show()"> <img src="../../../../assets/Acerca de mí.png">
    <br> Acerca de mí </button> 

</div>


<app-modal #modalAcerca class="modal-demo" [maximizable]="true" [backdrop]="false">
  <ng-container class="app-modal-header">Acerca De Mí</ng-container>
  <ng-container class="app-modal-body">
    <h3>MODAL DIALOG</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container class="app-modal-footer">
   
  </ng-container>
</app-modal>
```

El problema es que a la hora de querer modificar su apariencia en css(por ejemplo cambiar el color de la barra del header) me es imposible.

Ya intenté utilizando **.app-modal-header**, y también inspeccionando el modal, donde me figura que el nombre de la clase es **class="ui-modal-header"** pero el estilo sigue siendo el mismo.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar a solucionarlo me salvarian. Gracias

Comment: Ya probaste ejecutando tu proyecto en Modo incognito (Si usas Chrome) o Ventana Privada (Si usas Firefox). Puede ser la caché

Answer (score 0):

Algo debe estar interfiriendo en tu código con la asignación de estilos. en el ejemplo que te dejo a continuación no tengo problemas al reasignar estilos al header del modal.

Puedes probar agregando la regla `!important` al final de cada propiedad para que le de mayor relevancia. Por ejemplo `background-color: black !important;`

También es importante aclarar que a veces la memoria caché del navegador hace parecer que los estilos no se aplican. Intenta forzar el borrado de caché y revisa nuevamente.

```css
.app-modal-header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button type="button" (click)="modalAcerca.show()"> <img src="../../../../assets/Acerca de mí.png">
    <br> Acerca de mí </button> 
</div>
<br>
<app-modal #modalAcerca class="modal-demo" [maximizable]="true" [backdrop]="false">
  <ng-container class="app-modal-header">Acerca De Mí</ng-container>
  <ng-container class="app-modal-body">
    <h3>MODAL DIALOG</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container class="app-modal-footer">
  </ng-container>
</app-modal>
```